# Are there any FTP programs which can automatically send the contents of a folder to a remote server?

Tags: ftp, automation, file-transfer

Are there any FTP programs which can automatically copy (or rather 'move') the contents of a folder to a remote server?  I have of course googled this but only really found one or two ancient products which look really clunky and unmaintained. I was wondering if there's a way to do this from the command line or any better solution to the base problem.

In more detail, new files get written to a folder every few hours. These new files need to be FTP'd elsewhere and then deleted. Mirroring or synchonisation systems are probably out of the picture as we need to delete the source files once they've been successfully transferred.

If it's easier, the 'solution' could pull the files off the server (rather than the server pushing them to the client). The computers will both be Windows OS.

Comment: This isn't a programming question. It might belong on http://superuser.com or http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used a program called FTP Auto Sync: http://ftp-auto-sync.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could use any off the shelf FTP program that supports command line and schedule a task on Windows Scheduler to run every 10 minutes. Check the folder, and move any files to the FTP site.